# Multiple emails and attachments, reusing memory stream

Tags: c#, file, memory-optimization

I am generating a pdf form based on user input from an MVC website form. The pdf is genrated using the [Foxit .NET SDK](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/net-sdk/), then attached to three separate emails, generated using [Postal](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal). It has been requested that the file not be saved to disk at any stage.

I have not worked a lot with files or `MemoryStreams` before so would just like to know if my code is following the standard practices for managing memory and performance etc.

```
MergeDocument document = new MergeDocument(); // The PDF File Object
// ... Populate and create the pdf file

// Generate and Send the emails
// To the user
dynamic useremail = new Email("FormSubmitted");
useremail.To = User.EmailAddress;
useremail.Attach(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(document.Draw()), "OrderForm.pdf"));
useremail.Send();

// To the Vendor
dynamic vendoremail = new Email("FormSubmittedVendor");
vendoremail.To = Vendor.EmailAddress;
vendoremail.Attach(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(document.Draw()), "OrderForm.pdf"));
vendoremail.Send();

// To us
dynamic internalemail = new Email("FormSumbittedUs"); // To: is hardcoded in view.
internalemail.Attach(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(document.Draw()), "OrderForm.pdf"));
internalemail.Send();
```

Is it ok to create new `MemoryStream` objects for each email?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is ok, to create a new `MemoryStream` 3 times, but I have to ask, why you don't create one Attachment adding it to each of the emails like so

```
var attachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(document.Draw()), "OrderForm.pdf");  
useremail.Attach(attachment);
vendoremail.Attach(attachment);
internalemail.Attach(attachment);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that initially but received a `One of the streams has already been used and can't be reset to the origin.` exception

Comment: @jake you just have to rewind the stream